# Check in / Check out issue in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, versioning

There are two scenarios below, of which one works fine but another does not.

### Scenario #1 - check out, make changes, exit - works fine

- I Checkout and open an Office document (Excel, PowerPoint, word etc.)
- I make some changes and try to close the file
- I get a warning message asking if I want to check In or Discard Check out and the action is performed correctly.

### Scenario #2 - check out, do not make changes, exit - does not work fine

- I Checkout and open an Office document (Excel, PowerPoint, word etc.)
- I do not make any changes and try to close the file
- I do not get a warning message asking if I want to check In or Discard Check out and the file remains check out

I know a few workarounds, but would like to know if there is any way I can get the warning message to appear.

Could anyone please help me making the second scenario work?

Comment: Any errors in the ULS?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the 'red x' to exit, use the File Tab, one of the first options listed in the body portion (center of screen-ish) should be Check In.